# Testing with Spring and Maven: applicationContext

Tags: spring, unit-testing, maven

Seems that question old as world, but I still can't find out the solution..

I'm trying to run simple test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext.xml", "/PersonsPopulateTest-context.xml"})
@Transactional
public class PersonsPopulateTest {
```

Files are at:

```
src
   main
      resources
           applicationContext.xml
```

and

```
src        
   test
      resources
          PersonsPopulateTest-context.xml
```

So after building these files are at **target/classes** and **target/test-classes**

But mvn test command still says: Failed to load ApplicationContext

What official docs say:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// ApplicationContext will be loaded from "/applicationContext.xml" and "/applicationContext-test.xml"
// in the root of the classpath
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/applicationContext.xml", "/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class MyTest {
    // class body...
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks,
Vlaidimir

UPDATE. surefire-reports:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration.
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
... 30 more
```

Comment: Can you show the exact error message with stacktrace?

Comment: I think the `applicationContext.xml` has to be located in your `src/test/resources`. AFAIK Tests cannot access the `src/main` folders.

Comment: @Maroe: No, tests can access the main classpath. If they cannot, how can they load classes under test?

Comment: I've added applicationContext.xml as well in src/test/resources and it apper in target/test-classes, but test still failed with the same error

Comment: Valid point, axtavt, but as far as I experienced the set up of unit tests I never had access to the resources - I ever had a copy in `src/test/resources` - I'll check this out...

Comment: just do this **classpath:applicationContext.xml** instead of **/applicationContext.xml** your problem should go away, This will load the application context as long as it is in the run time class path, in this case placing applicationContext.xml in **src/test/resources** or **src/main/resources** should work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think Maven simply didn't include the XML file from main/resources.

You could try to specify explicitly what to include in the pom.xml.

Let me know if the following configuration has worked:

```
    <!-- Add this directly after the <build>-opening tag -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*local.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

This is something I use in your case. You can edit this if you don't have properties files to be included.

Comment: Maven include all from `src/test/resources` and `src/main/resources` by default. You could easy check this files in your target after `package`. So obviously problem not in this. I suppose just wrong context declaration as pointed in comment by Prasanna Talakanti.

Answer (score 9):

My test context file is under **src\test\resources\spring** folder.
I managed to load the context with

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:**/test-context.xml"})
```

But reference (in test-context.xml) to the application-context.xml which is under **src\main\resources\spring** folder failed

I managed to load the application-context by creating a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext in the test class with

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"classpath:spring/application-context.xml","classpath:spring/model-context.xml"});
```

Let me know if this helps or might create any other issues.

Comment: I managed to refer the application-context.xml in test-context.xml with <import resource="classpath*:spring/application-context.xml" />

Answer (score 5):

your application context must be included in classpath and put * :

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:*/application-context.xml" })
```

Comment: Best way to locate your xml

Answer (score 3):

I think best practice is to put your application context file for testing PersonsPopulateTest-context.xml under src/test/resources. This file will be copied into **target/test-classes** and you can refer to it in your test class as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:**/PersonsPopulateTest-context.xml"})
@Transactional
public class PersonsPopulateTest {

}
```

If you still want to refer to applicationContext.xml under src/main/resources, then you have to include it as follow:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"file:src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
public class PersonsPopulateTest {

}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- Add this directly after the <build>-opening tag in the your pom-->
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    </includes>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I had the same issue and it worked when I ran maven test with the JDK6 instead of JDK8 (in my case this is a legacy application)

If it helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. For me the test was running successfully via eclipse. However, when I ran `mvn test`, it was giving me error: **Failed to load ApplicationContext**

> Fix: Added the src/test/resources directory to classpath of surefire
>   plugin as-

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>      
            </configuration>
```

[Adding classpath to SureFire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, all files were successfully copied to **target/classes** and **target/test-classes**, still **spring** could not find them.

Problem disappeared when I explicitly specified versions for **maven-surefire-plugin** and **maven-resources-plugin** in **pom**

Comment: what the versions did you set ? i try to set all version of this plugins but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:
Actually in my case the problem was in `Compile on Save` option enabled. I use Netbeans, and the option was set to `For test  execution only`. This value compiles changed files and replaces resources with new files. However, due to usage of application resources additionally to test resources, `For test  execution only` produces incorrectly generated resources in `target` folder.

Changing `Compile on Save=For test  execution only`

to `Compile on Save=Disable` **fixes the problem.**

The text below is also correct, but sometimes does not work. It was working only till I restarted Netbeans IDE. However, the details of the reason of the problem are correct, hence, I prefer to leave the test.

---

OLD:
In my situation I have `appContext-test.xml` in `src/main/resources`.
When I change any code and launch one unit test (not all of them) it recompiles and correctly executed. But if I launch same unit test again it is failed with the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`.

I have changed `pom.xml` from

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

to

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

and now all work fine.

The **error was due** to `appContext-test.xml` uses `src/main/resources/my.properties` file with a lot of variables like

```
database.url = ${database.url}
database.username = ${database.username}
database.password = ${database.password}
```

that are filled during a build. However, if you skip `src/main/resources` in `testResource`, then `my.properties` is added to `target/classes/my.properties` as is, i.g. without a substitution. This file of course breaks the context.

PS: You can remove `${project.basedir}/` - it is my custom thing.

Answer (score 0):

Within your integration test class, try add

```
@Test
public void contextLoads(){
}
```