# How to run tests after deployment using Maven?

Tags: maven, deployment, junit, integration-testing, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to decide how to create a set of Acceptance Tests for a Java-EE web application.

Here's the setup: Maven is used to generate a WAR file and deploy it into Glassfish. On deployment, the MySQL database schema is automatically updated from model classes using Hibernate ("hbm2ddl=auto" option).

The Acceptance Tests need to test the deployed code by invoking various methods and checking the results are as expected(*). We wrote an additional set of packages to hook into an existing system so the Acceptance Tests should show how these can be integrated into the existing codebase.

(*) This may sound more like Unit/Integration Testing but they are Acceptance Tests in the sense that they should prove what we did works and they need to be run after deployment so there is a database in place.

From the above, my current thinking is to use JUnit to check expected values etc. The bit I'm struggling with is how to invoke these tests *after* deployment. "deploy" is Maven's last phase so not sure if this is possible?

Comment: I'm not sure that you really need to deploy before testing. For integration test, we can use DBUnit and the database will be available in place.

Comment: Thanks but is this true even if the database is generated from the classes using Hibernate? I've never used DBUnit (but have come across it on here a few times when trying to find answers for this) so would need to look into this.

Comment: yes, it's true; I currently use it for integration testing.

Comment: This is going to show up my lack of knowledge but the codebase I'm adding to uses a "seam-managed Hibernate session". This is instantiated via a call to Component.getInstance("hibernateSession"). This call fails when it is made prior to deployment with a "No application context active" error. Not sure why this is - but even if it succeeded I'm confused about how/where the database Hibernate is referencing would exist if this were done prior to deploying on the Application Server.

Comment: no, I think it's normal because you just begin with tests. You must initialize the application context before running tests for that way to work. For example you may refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104372/testing-with-spring-and-maven-applicationcontext

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because that phase is called `deploy` doesn't mean that you have to use it for deploying your application for testing.  In fact, it should only be used for "deploying" the artifact to a maven repository.  Read through the description of the [Maven lifecycle phases](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) and you'll see that there are some phases dedicated to your use case:

```
pre-integration-test
integration-test
post-integration-test
```

Have a look at the [Cargo Maven plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin).  It's made to deploy your WAR file to various containers for testing.  They definitely show demos of use cases like the one you describe on your site.  I would expect that ultimately, you can be using Cargo to deploy to your container ( from one of the earlier phases like pre-integration-test )

Note, Jenkins also has a plugin that is a wrapper around the Cargo plugin.  So you might do what you need via Jenkins.  Also note, you don't need to run your Jenkins build job as mvn clean deploy.  You could have one build job that just runs the integration tests, and fires another "deploy" job only when it succeeds.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply - a good point that the phases can be used in an ad hoc way. But there's something pretty fundamental I'm not understanding here. I write the Java code, package it up into a WAR file and then deploy it to the Application Server (Glassfish). It's the Application Server where the database resides (and is updated from Hibernate) so how would I be able to test communications with the database etc. prior to deployment? Surely the database wouldn't exist? Is this where the containers come in - do they somehow simulate an Application Server without needing full deployment?

Comment: GlassFish is a Cargo supported container. It supports deploying to an existing external container, or an ad hoc container fired up and torn down, living only for the purpose of the testing.  I guess what I'm saying is that Cargo is a high quality product made for your use case.  I'd check it out ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you really need to do stuff after deployment, then you can either run failsafe, and by implication JUnit) as part of the deploy phase.

What I usually do, if to have seperate module. So, you can have one maven project, which contains your project and a separate 'deployment test' project. Then, building the parent project will build and run your war and then run the deployment tests. You can use junit as normal.

The second fits better into jenkins because you'll still have a single project as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Am leaning towards doing something like this. One downside is I would have liked to be able to easily run/debug the tests in Eclipse. I guess this would be possible through remote debugging but a lot more long-winded.