# Spring ContextConfiguration Initializers not run under maven test

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I have a Junit test running flawlessely within a Spring application context.  The application context includes two xml files as well as an initializer.  The JUnit base class is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration( locations = { "classpath:/applicationContext.xml", 
                                     "classpath:/applicationcontext-security.xml"}, 
                                     initializers = com.abc.ConfigurationInitializer.class )
@TransactionConfiguration
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
{......
```

However when running the test under maven the application context fails to load and this is because the initializer class is not run.

Why is the Initializer(s) class not being run?

Comment: in which directory are the files `applicationContext.xml` and `applicationcontext-security.xml` located? -- btw: is it correct that the security file use a lower case `c` in word context?

Comment: When you say running flawlessly, do you mean in Eclipse? If so, what is the build path for Eclipse? Does it include a more recent version of junit?

Comment: i think you have same problem like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104372/testing-with-spring-and-maven-applicationcontext

Comment: I should emphasize the file location is fine - the problem is that the initializer class (initializers=ConfigurationInitializer.class) is not being called!

Answer (score 0):

My bad - The initializer ran it simply crashed very soon thereafter